# gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir /home/USER/.gnupg

Tags: gnupg, ownership

I get a warning about unsafe ownership of `~/.gnupg`:

```bash
curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg
  gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/USER/.gnupg'
```

- I have tried the following and nothing worked:

  ```bash
  chown -R $(USER) ~/.gnupg/
  ```

  ```bash
  find ~/.gnupg -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
  find ~/.gnupg -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
  ```

  ```bash
  sudo gpgconf --kill dirmngr
  sudo chown -R USER:USER /home/USER/.gnupg
  chmod 700 /home/USER/.gnupg
  chmod 600 ~/.gnupg/*
  ```
- ```bash
  ls -al /home/elias/.gnupg

    drwx------  4 USER USER  4096 Jul  1 19:33 .
    drwxr-xr-x 96 USER USER 20480 Jul 10 11:19 ..
    drw-------  2 USER USER  4096 Feb 13  2019 crls.d
    drw-------  2 USER USER  4096 Aug 13  2018 private-keys-v1.d
    -rw-------  1 USER USER  2305 Feb 13  2019 pubring.kbx
    -rw-------  1 USER USER   584 Feb 13  2019 pubring.kbx~
    -rw-------  1 USER USER  1200 Aug 13  2018 trustdb.gpg
  ```

May be of relevance:

```bash
error:45 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hugin/hugin-builds/ubuntu bionic Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]

Hit:32 https://www.icesi.edu.co/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/ InRelease

error:25 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
  The following signatures were not valid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>

error:30 http://apt.insynchq.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures were not valid: EXPKEYSIG A684470CACCAF35C Insynchq Inc <services@insynchq.com>

E: The repository 'https://packages.sury.org/php bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
   N: Updating from such a repository cant be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hugin/hugin-builds/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
   N: Updating from such a repository cant be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
   GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures were not valid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
   GPG error: http://apt.insynchq.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures were not valid: EXPKEYSIG A684470CACCAF35C Insynchq Inc <services@insynchq.com>
```

Extra info that it was asked:

```bash
ls -al /usr/share/keyrings/
```

results:

```bash
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 10 11:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 621 root root 20480 Jul 10 13:50 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1795 Jul 10 11:52 githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2274 May 11 13:19 ubuntu-advantage-cis.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2236 May 11 13:19 ubuntu-advantage-esm-apps.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2264 May 11 13:19 ubuntu-advantage-esm-infra-trusty.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2275 May 11 13:19 ubuntu-advantage-fips.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  7399 Sep 18  2018 ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  6713 Oct 27  2016 ubuntu-archive-removed-keys.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  4097 Feb  6  2018 ubuntu-cloudimage-keyring.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     0 Jan 17  2018 ubuntu-cloudimage-removed-keys.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1227 May 27  2010 ubuntu-master-keyring.gpg
```

Extra info 2:

```bash
sudo env | grep '^HOME='
```

results:

```bash
HOME=/home/elias
```

Comment: You probably should use ‘gpg‘ alone, not ‘sudo gpg‘.

Comment: Dont work....  it says "refuse access"

Comment: If `sudoers` isn't configured for `elias` to execute commands as `elias`, it's going to default to `root`, leading to the warnings, as in that context, `~/.gnupg` isn't owned by `root`. Also, `gpg` shouldn't require `sudo` - do you know why you're unable to access it without `sudo`? Is `/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg` not accessible to `elias`; if so, it seems it would be easier to copy the keyring to `~`, use `gpg`, the copy it back with `sudo`?

Comment: @JW0914 the info that you asked was added to the question. All keyrings are owned by root:root. Please elaborate more on the final proposition of yours.

Comment: Does `sudo env | grep '^HOME='` give your home directory or root's? If it's yours then I have an answer for you

Comment: updated question with extra info. It gives mine. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look a moment at what this command is doing (simplified for the illustration)

> ```
> curl … | sudo gpg … -o /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg
> ```

The `curl` part goes off and gets something we are going to give to `gpg`; no problem there.

The `sudo gpg` command runs `gpg` as `root`, but with an unchanged `HOME` directory. When `gpg` runs it checks `$HOME/.gpg` for ownership and permissions. In this case it is running as `root` but finds that instead of the directory being owned by `root` it's being owned by `USER`. Appropriately it complains, loudly

> ```
> gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/USER/.gnupg'
> ```

You mentioned that you cannot omit the `sudo`, and I would assume this is because you need root permissions to write to `/usr/share/keyrings/`. The solution in this case may be to tell `sudo` to change the `HOME` directory value to match the `root` user

```
sudo -H gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg
```

The documentation (`man sudo`) explains,

> `-H`, `--set-home` Request that the security policy set the `HOME` environment variable to the home directory specified by the target user's password database entry.

Another option is to run `gpg` without `sudo` and write the key to your own `HOME` directory, and then use `sudo` to move it to the target directory

```
gpg --dearmor -o githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg &&
    sudo mv -f githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
```